# C# Regular Expression Look Ahead S

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate a `string` to see if it is at least 6 digits long and has at least 1 `int`.

```
 string text = "I want to run 10 miles daily";
 string pattern = @"(?=\.*\d).{6,}";
 Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
 Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Please explain me why I am getting the below output:

**"10 miles daily"**

Answer (score 4):

The reason you get **"10 miles daily"** is because you specify a positive lookahead `(?=\.*\d)` which matches a literal dot zero or more times and then a digit.

That assertion succeeds at the position before the 1 where it matches zero times a dot and then a digit:

```
I want to run 10 miles daily
..............|
```

From that moment you match any character zero or more times which will match  `.{6,}` which matches:

```
I want to run 10 miles daily
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You could update your regex to remove the backslash before the dot and use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the line:

[`^(?=.*\d).{6,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/QJ64Ln/1)

**That would match**

- `^` Assert begin of a line
- `(?=.*\d)` Positive lookahead to assert what what followes contains a digit
- `.{6,}` Match any character 6 more times
- `$` Assert the end of a line

Comment: @Chandan Gupta This is the best exact answer to your question and explained very well. Thm Lee's answer is also very good and offers an additional insight into your original expression.

Answer (score 2):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but I assume you're looking for a working `RegEx`. Your statement was `I want to validate a string to see if it is at least 6 digits long and has at least 1 int.`. I assume you mean `at least 6 characters long (including white space) and has at least 1 int.`

This should do it (C#):

`@"^(?=.*\d+)(?=.*[\w]).{6,}$";`

RegEx Analyzer: [UltraPico Expresso RegEx Tool](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm)

[image]

Test code and output (C#)

```
tatic void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "abcdef";
    Match match;
    string pattern = @"^(?=.*\d+)(?=.*[\w]).{6,}$";

    match = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine("Text:'"+text + "'. Matched:" + match.Success + ". Value:" + match.Value);

    text = "abcdefg";
    match = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine("Text:'" + text + "'. Matched:" + match.Success + ". Value:" + match.Value);

    text = "abcde1";
    match = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine("Text:'" + text + "'. Matched:" + match.Success + ". Value:" + match.Value);

    text = "abcd21";
    match = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine("Text:'" + text + "'. Matched:" + match.Success + ". Value:" + match.Value);

    text = "abcd dog cat 21";
    match = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine("Text:'" + text + "'. Matched:" + match.Success + ". Value:" + match.Value);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`\.*\d` this means string ends with a digit.

`(?=\.*\d)` this take target digit in string

`(?=\.*\d).` this pattern means, in a string, everything after the digit found.

`(?=\.*\d).{6,}` every characters after `digit` and match must be at least 6 characters.

You need this regex : `(?=.*\d).{6,}$`. This return as a result at least 6 character and has at least one of them is digit

Answer (score 0):

```
\.*\d  => means a digit preceded by literal dots(`.`)
```

and `*` means repeating `(0 ~ ) numbers` of the character, dot(`.`).

Thus, as you can see, there is no character dot(`.`) in your input string. So regex engine try to match by evaluating `*`'s repeating number as `zero`, `0`.

As a result, your regex may be interpreted as follows.

```
(?=\d).{6,}
```

Yes, this regex means `one digit` followed by more than 5 numbers of any characters.

But, `{6,}` means `greedy` search which searches `possible maximum length string`. On the other hand, `lazy`mode( `{6,}?` in this case) searches possible minimum length string.

You can try this `lazy mode` regex and compare to the above `greedy` one's result.

```
(?=\d).{6,}?
```